# How to get a list of the field names in a table in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have my entities defined as follows,

```
[Table("AuditZone")]
    public class AuditZone
    {
        public AuditZone()
        {
            AuditZoneUploadedCOESDetails = new List<UploadedCOESDetails>();
            AuditZonePostcode = new List<Postcodes>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DoNotAudit]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }     
        public bool Valid { get; set; }

        [DoNotAudit]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [DoNotAudit]
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DoNotAudit]
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        [DoNotAudit]
        public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual UserProfile CreatedByUser { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile ModifiedByUser { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UploadedCOESDetails> AuditZoneUploadedCOESDetails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Postcodes> AuditZonePostcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Some of the fields have an attribute called `DoNotAudit`.

I need to be able to get a list of the fields in the table that do not have that `DoNotAudit` attribute.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

```
  public IEnumerable<string> GetFields(string tableName)
        {


            var table = typeof(AISDbContext).GetProperties().Select(n => n.PropertyType) // here we get all properties of contect class
                             .Where(n => n.Name.Contains("DbSet") && n.IsGenericType) // here we select only DBSet collections
                             .Select(n => n.GetGenericArguments()[0])
                            .Where(n => n.Name == tableName);

            var doNotAuditList = table.GetType()
                                       .GetProperties()
                                       .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotAudit), false).Any())
                                       .Select(p => p.Name)
                                       .ToList();
            return doNotAuditList;

        }
```

Updated query

```
 var doNotAuditList = table.First().GetProperties()
                  .Where(p=> p.PropertyType.FindInterfaces(new TypeFilter((t,o) => t == typeof(IEnumerable)), null).Length == 0)
                  .Where(n => n.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DoNotAudit>().FirstOrDefault() == null)
                                       .Select(p => p.Name)
                                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` is already the type you need, so `table.GetType()` is not correct. Just use `table.GetProperties()` as below:

```
        var doNotAuditList = table.First()
                                  .GetProperties()
                                   .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotAudit), false).Any() == false
                                   && p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual == false)
                                  .Select(p => p.Name)
                                  .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
`table` is of type `IQueriable<Type>`, so a call to `.First()` is needed to get the actual object.

**EDIT**
Updated Linq query to ignore all virtual properties and properties marked `DoNotAudit`.

Comment: table does not have a GetProperties method

Comment: Sorry, `table` is actually an `IQueriable<Type>`, you need to call .First() to get the table Type object.

Comment: it returns the navigation properties as well, how can I limit that? All i want is the properties..

Comment: Add the following criteria to your where clause: `&& p.PropertyType.FindInterfaces(new TypeFilter((t,o) => t == typeof(IEnumerable)), null).Length == 0`

Comment: i updated my query in the code above, but I am seeing Valid, CreatedByUser, ModifiedByUser.  Description is not shown at all.  I should only see Description and Valid..

Comment: Updated the Linq query to ignore all virtual properties as well as properties marked `DoNotAudit`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45562/discussion-between-wdosanjos-and-user2206329)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection of the Type `typeof(Poco).GetProperties()`   can lead to different results to what is actually tracked in EF.   EF will ignore some types, some types may have Ignore annotations.
Complex Types need special attention.

If you want the EF view of the model, then access the `MetadataWorkspace`.

**Some basic dump Metadata to debug console code...**

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void EFToolsTest() {
    //  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.dataspace(v=vs.110).aspx
        var context = new YourContext(); // DbContext type
        ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var xyz = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
        foreach (var ET in xyz) {
            foreach (var sp in ET.Properties) {
                Debug.WriteLine(sp.Name + ":" + sp.MaxLength);// just as an example

                }
            }
        }
```

or via the DataSpace.OSpace

```
   public static  void DumpContextManagedTypeProps() {
       var context = new YourContent();
        ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
        IEnumerable<EntityType> managedTypes = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
        foreach (var managedType in managedTypes.Where(mt=>mt.Ful) {
        Console.WriteLine(managedType.FullName);
        // propertyInfo and other useful info is available....
        foreach ( var p in managedType.Properties) {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name );
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```